# How to access object data from one method to another

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am newbie in Java and trying to develop sample web app using GET and POST mapping. I got the object data using getters and setters in GET and POST method as well. But the same object data is not available in another POST method.

here is the code...

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Controller
public class PatientController {    
    
    static String jSonstr;
      ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
    
          
    @GetMapping("/patient")
    public static String patientForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("patient", new PatientDataModel());
        return "patient";
    }

    @PostMapping("/patient")
    public static String patientSubmit(@ModelAttribute PatientDataModel patient, Model model, Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
    
        
        
        obj = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(patient);
        model.addAttribute("patient", patient);
        
        model.addAttribute("patientjson", obj);
        
        jSonstr = obj.toString();
                
        return "result";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/patienteventhub")
    public static String patienteventHubSubmit(@ModelAttribute PatientDataModel patient, Model model, Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        
        // need to write code here
        
        return "resulteventhub";
    }
    
          
}
```

further, for data rendering, I am using thymeleaf.

what I am trying to achieve is, access the data in the object (`patient and obj`) in the method `patienteventHubSubmit`

what I learnt is , all the methods are static so it means , I can access the variables and data without creating instance of the class.

please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not mere methods these methods are gateway to your application, Since you are listening to incoming parameters PatientModel and obj, you will have to explicitly pass them from UI or client.

Comment: OK. but how should I explicitly pass them from UI ? any example please ?

Comment: It's a post mapping, use a http form or a json payload. I think you need more reading before coding!